# Is it possible to write a view wrapper？

Tags: android

Now，I want to replace all view by my own **AppCompatDelegate**.
And override method **createView** so that I can update all the views in project.

Now I can do update like this:

```
public class UpdatedView extends View
```

in **AppCompatDelegate** :

```
public View createView(String name) {
   if ("View".equals(name)) {
      return UpdatedView();
   }
}
```

Now, the problem I'm facing is that is it possible to create a view wrapper for all View. So that I can write like this

```
public class ViewWrapper extends View{
    View realView;

    @Override
    public void methods() {
       //override the method which is need, like ondraw, onClick
       doUpdateThings();
       realView.methods();
    } 
}
```

wrapper all views like this.

```
public View createView(String name) {
   if ("View".equals(name)) {
      return UpdatedViewWrapper(new View());
   }
}
```

### I want to know whether it's possible or not, and safe or not.

Someting added: it seems, I don't need the replace **delegate** but override **onCreateView** is enough.

Comment: why do you need such functionality?

Comment: It's easy to update all views to do things what I want. Such as  statistics,  prevent all repeat click event.

Comment: Comment something more for why i want view wrapper.If possible, ViewWrapper helps to avoid creating lots of subclasses like UpdatedTextView, UpdatedImageView.